# postcss - css variable as argument inside postcss-mixins

Tags: css, postcss, css-variables

I have a mixin made with [postcss-mixins](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-mixins) and I want to use a css variable as argument, but it isn't working.

```
:root {
    --padd: 2rem;
}

@define-mixin position $place, $val {
    @if $place == end { right: $(val); }
    @if $place == start { left: $(val); }
}
```

And then I call it:

```
.foo1 {
   @mixin position end, 2rem; /* it works -> right: 2rem; */
}

.foo2 {
   @mixin position end, var(--padd); /* doesn't work -> right: var(--padd); - it should output 2rem  */
}
```

How can I manage to be able using css variables with postcss-mixins?

Comment: Try https://github.com/GitScrum/postcss-at-rules-variables

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work with `postcss-mixins`

Comment: It does for me (had to put it at the beginning of the plugin list).

Comment: I end up by doing mixins in JS ;)

Comment: is it working nowadays?